Redisson connect with aws elastic cache with default user
I am trying to connect to aws elastic cache for redis via java client Redisso
Version : 5.0.6
Encryption at Transit : enabled
Redis AUTH default user access : Yes

Redisson:
Version :  3.14.1 

Connection Fails with
UTC|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 58
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|redisson-netty-2-6|2024-05-28 08:31:29.772 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1671|Plaintext after DECRYPTION (
  0000: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX   41 75 74 XX XX XX XX 69  NOAUTH Authenti
  0010: xx xx xx xx xx 6E 20 72   xx 71 75 XX XX 65 xx xx  cation required.
  0020: xx xx                                              ..
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|11|redisson-netty-2-6|2024-05-28 08:31:29.774 UTC|SSLEngineImpl.java:754|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|11|redisson-netty-2-6|2024-05-28 08:31:29.774 UTC|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|redisson-netty-2-6|2024-05-28 08:31:29.774 UTC|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:529|WRITE: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2

I use rediss:// Redisson config as below,
Config config = new Config();
            config.useReplicatedServers().addNodeAddress("rediss://primary.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379")
            .addNodeAddress("rediss://replica-1.use1.cache.amazonaws:6379");

            RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config); 
            redisson.getLock("Mylock").lock();
            System.out.println("Hello, Lock is acquired..");
            redisson.getLock("Mylock").unlock();
            System.out.println("Hello, Lock is unlocked....");

What auth credentials I must use, or I cant get this working until I move to redis IAM user etc.
